# How to use SingleChildScrollView without fixed width and height?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am working the project and there is requirement to not use fixed width and height. However, I am getting pixel overflowed error. I used Expanded and other widgets but still getting an error. Code look likes this.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        minScale: 1,
        maxScale: 1,
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [w],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In Column children we can add multiple children and page height grows with it. However, using Expanded widget is not solving the issue and getting pixel overflowed error. Using Container and MediaQuery is not required. Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `body: InteractiveViewer(` are you using other widget on top of it? It would be easier if you can provide full sample snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, full snippet I cannot provide. but w is a widget whose height is bigger than page size.

Comment: I've tested with `Scaffold( body: InteractiveViewer(` and `w` as container but failed to reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Container(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: [w],
),),)
```